# Download files from the file with same path directory

Tags: shell-script, download, http

I need a simple command/script which allows me to download hundreds of files from the file in the same path structure as on the remote server.

For example:

```
http://download.com/path/to/the/folder/file.txt
```

will download to:

```
/path/to/the/folder/
```

on the server

Comment: Did you try `wget -r http://www.example.com/path/`?

Comment: I can not use this command for more than one file :/

Comment: You don't give it a list of files, you give it a base path, and it recursively fetches all of the contents.  That's what the `-r` is for.

Comment: Cool :) I will use if. However can you help me if I will have a file with more links (let's say links.txt). How I can download all of them at once?

Answer (score 1):

U will need file filled with links.

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST="list.txt"

for row in `cat $LIST`; do
        wget -x $row
        sleep 5
done
```

Man:

```
‘-x’
‘--force-directories’
The opposite of ‘-nd’—create a hierarchy of directories, even if one would not have been created otherwise. E.g. ‘wget -x http://fly.srk.fer.hr/robots.txt’ will save the downloaded file to fly.srk.fer.hr/robots.txt.
```